# jquery show function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying some jQuery code and my `show()` function doesn't seem to work.

here is my jQuery code:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $("#dropdown").show();
});
```

The link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dTbN/).

Comment: ...and where are you calling this so-called slidedown() function?

Comment: was trying show and slidedown, i edited the question

Comment: `button` is not equal to `#button` or `:button`. `button` is for `<button></button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no element being accessed by `$("button")`

add `id="button"` to the button element and change jquery to `$("#button")`

please do more research before asking such questions.

Answer (score 0):

add a # before button

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $("#dropdown").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the rightful jquery version? Or may be you should replace the `https://` or `http://` to `//` e.g `<script type="text/javascript" src="//yourplugin.js"></script>` and also if you have multiple of div containing that particular `id` you should use `$("div#youdivid).show();` if that doesn't work you should do a little cross checking on your work!